# How to use Picasso library with Androidx?

Tags: android, gradle, picasso, androidx

I have an One year old code, which I worked so hard on, this code uses **picasso** library in some places to download images and use them. Today I try to improve my code, migrate to **androidx** and upgrade **Gradle** to the latest version, but it doesn't seem to **sync** gradle file anymore, when I **comment** the implementation for **picasso** library, the sync goes **smoothly** again.

Google recommends migrating to androidx to be able to serve the latest android versions, the latest play services and jetpack libraries. What is the problem? and how it can be solved?

This is my Gradle app level file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ramikabbani.sheikhsouk"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
//

}
```

and this is my top level project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the old project app level gradle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.dalilukom.dalilukom"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 21
            versionName "1.21"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
        //implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    //    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    //    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    //    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    //    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and this is the top level gradle file for the old project too:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just migrate to androidx and get the Picasso dependency for androidx on your grade file. You should be fine

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I already migrated to AndroidX and trying to use the dependency provided by picasso which is `'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`, as you can see from the first gradle file. But it never compiles until I remove picasso dependency.
Do you have another source that can give the library for picasso that works with AndroidX.

Comment: I used the same version as yours and it worked fine. Try using Glide then and remove Picasso... I personally use glide more

Comment: Probably other people are using `android.enableJetifier=true` in your gradle.properties in order for picasso to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a workaround.

In build.gradle (project:..), of the project Gradle file, downgrade the plugin to 7.2.1 and recompile.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}
```

It works. It seems like it's unsupported on later versions.

But I think you should change the file gradle.properties (Project properties)  under `android.useAndroidX=true`.

Put:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Putting whole file content of gradle.properties (Project properties):

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```